# How to redirect multiple url in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I need support for nginx configuration, especially for location blok.

Just like that:

```
localhost/issue_x/ -> show as a autoindex /var/lib/jenkins/issue_x/
```

and

```
localhost/issue_x/foobar/*view*/ -> show file foobar as a plain text in webpage from /var/lib/jenkins/issue_x/archive/foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your desire well:

```
location /issue_x {
  root /var/lib/jenkins;
  autoindex on;
}

location ~ /issue_x/foobar/.*view.*/ {
  alias /var/lib/jenkins/issue_x/archive/;
  rewrite ^.* /foobar last;
}
```

Comment: It works, Thanks. But against review I use index foobar; to show file content

Comment: You're welcome :) You can accept my answer if you think it's good.